# Cisco-configuration syntax highlighting for TextMate/Sublime Text

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-15, cisco-ios-12

I would like to have syntax highlighting while perusing my configs - does anybody know of a good Cisco IOS syntax highlighting bundle for TextMate or Sublime Text?

Edited (2015-09-21) to add:

GitHub Atom Editor has a Cisco IOS syntax highlighter in their built in "packages" repo and it is easy to install. I think that Sublime Text is a better editor, but if you are not already invested in ST, I recommend giving Atom a look.

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though a [`.tmBundle`](http://polydistortion.net/monkey/archives/2006/06/24/003722.html) exists for syntax highlighting in Cisco IOS, it is very limited in scope.

Have you made or do you know of a better bundle?

Comment: Are you referring to this one, or something else? http://polydistortion.net/monkey/archives/2006/06/24/003722.html

Comment: @routelastresort Yes, I've linked it but it might be hard to see that `.tmBundle` is a link in my post :)

Comment: You should merge the info in this answer into your original question.

Comment: >[To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is _explicitly encouraged_.**](http://http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tried it yet but there is a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/illotum/IOS-Syntax) someone made for Cisco IOS Syntax Highlighting for Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is very limited in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Grab **Notepad++** which has many different language (formatting=parsing) options.  Though I don't have a specific one for Cisco, I'm sure someone's created one or you can define your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Network Tech](https://github.com/heyglen/network_tech/blob/master/README.md) if you use Sublime Text 3. I am the author.